# Why is my javascript try/catch block not firing?

Tags: javascript, html, function, try-catch

No code within my function will run unless I comment out the try/catch code entirely. Why is that? I keep adding code before and after the try/catch and in the try or the catch and nothing will ever run.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var y=3;
function message()
{
    try
    {
        alert("fdgg");
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        txt="Something went wrong, deal with it!"\n\n";
        txt+="Error crap " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt+="Click Ok to do stuff.";
        alert(txt);
    }
    alert("67");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Pooper" onclick="message()");
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably because `alert()` does not throw errors, so there is nothing to catch?

Comment: Also this string `txt="Something went wrong, deal with it!"\n\n"` is not well formatted. Change it for `txt="Something went wrong, deal with it! \n\n"`

Comment: Yes its not firing because you have a syntax error in your catch

Comment: @cdhowie In the question description it is specifically stated `No code within my function will run unless I comment out the try/catch code entirely`. So if that is indeed correct it has nothing to do with the lack of errors...

Comment: also you have an invalid input button tag - you seem to have closed it with `);` instead of `>` - [works if you sort out your syntax errors](http://jsfiddle.net/hxgcnLu2/1/) or [with errors](http://jsfiddle.net/hxgcnLu2/2/)

Comment: Your code has so many syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
txt="Something went wrong, deal with it!"\n\n";
```

to

```
txt="Something went wrong, deal with it!\n\n";
```